# Dynamic web widget

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

My vendor offers a widget creation service where I can login to their page, set initial values of a search form, after the save button is clicked, I can copy & paste the script code on my website to display a product search result widget.

I am thinking to change this static widget to a dynamic one. Since my programming knowledge is limited, can experts tell me if it's possible to login https remotely (using cURL) and set search form values equal to values on my page (every time my page content changes, it will change the form value), then save the form. So the widget script I pasted on my page will always be refreshed to new search result.

So the issue will involve cross domain, form submission & server/browser communication. I know a little jQuery, PHP, Ajax, cURL but so far I stuck with just having an idea but not really sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're over-thinking the problem, but you can correct me if I'm dead wrong...

It sounds like the widgets are created using a variety of different values that you can compile yourself from the information on their site. By using these values you could probably plug them directly into the code that you get the first time, without having to hit their service again. In this way, you could build a dynamic version of what they offer by replacing the values in the widget at whatever interval you choose (every time, hourly, daily... whatever).

Even if the amount of data they have is huge, you could start with a subset as a proof of concept.

I would also look into their service and see if they have an API. The service you describe may be their basic offering. There may be an API that offers just what you need, and maybe more.

Comment: The widget script looks something like this <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/customjs.php?widgetid=12345"></script>. I am going to check with their API service.